# Can we use Web Compiler 2022+ with scoped scss files?

Tags: visual-studio, razor, sass, razor-pages, web-compiler

I can easily generate the main CSS file from multiple SCSS files, and save the output in `wwwroot/css/generated-site.css` for example.

My concern is with Razor Page/View specific Sass file. Let's say I have:

```
Pages/Shared/SomeComponent.cshtml
Pages/Shared/SomeComponent.cshtml.scss
```

The code in the `.scss` file is not used.

How can I get the `Web Compiler 2022+` to compile it and merge the output in the generated `~/AppName.styles.css` that should include all Page/View specific styles.